Difference between 3 (not PDF/CDF) distribuitions
I have multiple (>20) variables that describe 3 different objects, and I wanted to see which variables differ the most across these 3 objects. I was thinking about using KL-divergence/KS-test/Jensen–Shannon divergence or something like that, but when I search them up, it seems that these metrics are for comparing probability distributions. What metric should I use in this case? I work in computational chem, so I'm not really sure what metric is appropriate in this case where I'm just comparing generic distributions.
Thanks!
